# <tr> onClick not working

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to turn my table rows into links using JS. I have it looking like this:

```
<tr onClick='javascript:window.location.href='url';'>
```

However, when I try to click, it doesn't go the page as I want. In fact, clicking seems to have no action.

Any help?

**Edit:**

As for the quotes, I forgot to mention that I'm echoing this with PHP. Here's my updated code:

```
echo "<tr onClick='window.location.href='url?id=" . $var . "';'></tr>";
```

Should I be doing some sort of escaping like `/"` in this case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all, ***no `javascript:` in event handlers*** - they contain JavaScript code, not an URL. It just works because `javascript:` is a label in this case and thus not a syntax error.
Besides that, any editor with proper syntax highlighting would have shown you that you are breaking the quoting as you are using single quotes for the HTML attribute and inside the attribute.

Here's the fixed code:

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href = 'url';">
```

Besides that, inline event handlers are dirty. Better attach them nicely using jQuery:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    location.href = 'url';
});
```

Comment: This is a "javascript" question not a jquery and you can't encourage that. What a concern.

Comment: @moses, if one tool is better for the job then the one asked for, by all means offer it.

Comment: Of course I can encourage that. Looking at his code Sennheiser is clearly a Javascript beginner and he'll write better JavaScript if he's not messing around with plain JS.

Comment: @jb, you don't know that the project is large. What make sense for a little job using jquery or any framework?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, if he can't code with plain JS, Should he learn jquery? Thus, can he code plain JS?

Comment: @moses, all I am saying is approaching every task with the same tool is simply a bad approach. Different tasks require different tools. The OP might not have known about jQuery so he didn't tag it as such, that doesn't mean it isn't a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, HTML attributes have to be surrounded by quotes, so if you need quotes *within* the attribute you need a different pairing. Try this:

```
<tr onClick="window.location.href='url';">
```

And if you are within a loop and echo'ing stuff out try PHP's HEREDOC syntax.

```
$out = '';
foreach ( $x as $y )
{
$out .= <<<HTML
<tr onClick="window.location.href='url';">
HTML;
}
echo $out;
```

Edit: added HEREDOC

Comment: I'm doing this inside a PHP loop, so I already have double quotes as the outermost quotes, and the rest are single quotes.

Comment: $out .= "<tr onclick=\" window.location.href = 'url'; \"></tr>";

Comment: I'm sorry but I honestly can't comprehend what you mean. Isn't there a simpler way to just escape the string I have? Forget that I mentioned a loop and imagine it's a PHP file with only one line - an echo that echoes the table row I have. How can I just escape that?

Comment: Why add all of those backslashes when you can use that special format and bypass it? ;)