# is tr element unclickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When I bind a handler to a  element

`$('tr').on('click', handler)`

And Then when I trigger the  element's click event, nothing happen

`$('tr').trigger('click')`

instead the  element within the  can response to the event

`$('tr td:first').trigger('click')`

So does it mean that `<tr>` element isn't clickable?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319638/tr-onclick-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your handler function do? It seems to work fine for me:

```
function handler(e){
    alert(e.target);
}

// attach event
$('tr').on('click', handler);

// manually trigger click
$('tr').trigger('click');
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/LnUNC/).

`<tr>`'s are DOM objects, so you should be able to attach events to them

Comment: Good example code! the <tr> can be triggered! something must be wrong with my code

Comment: I've found the mistake I made, I've been using `$('tr')` selecting the tr in the thead which has no event handler bind to it $('tbody tr:first').trigger('click') works fine

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation()` will also help.

```
$('tr').click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```